# Restriction for the data rendering into the table with Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, sails.js, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Angular component which fetches data from the service, which fetches data from REST API, which connected to data base. From a Component data goes to html-template and appears in a  with *ngFor.

Nothing special - no additional code. Everything works as expected.

But a problem is that the table renders only 30 first records. For example, if Im deleting the one record in a data base, who is between 0 and 29 index, the table updates with new data. And the last record, which before wasn't show, now shown at the last row.

Where Im wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: yes. `Observables` works that way. you should load them into variable at `ngOnInit` and use that variable in the `*ngFor` of your `html-template`. Reason is **same instance** changes in a observable will trigger the subscription again.

Comment: you mean, that Observable instance update the template? I know that. Problem is that I have only 30 rows in a table? And I have more than. How can I fix this restriction?

Comment: as i said load them into the component via code and pass the instance to the html.